# Android In-App Purchase in Alpha Testing of a subscription item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I uploaded and published my app in Alpha  testing and I downloaded the app through tester account. I used real SKU. So my problem is the following

When I am directed to Play Store I must buy the app even if I have enabled trial period of 7 days.

Here I should notice that in the main menu I have a button called Subscribe, which I think! its never going to be used if someone Clicks the buy button from Play Store

I check bank account and Merchant Center and the purchase has gone through as normal real purchase with an Order ID

Is this normal? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined your app as Paid you will never see that. You must setup your app as free and have a button inside your app